# XeLaTeX update [20201004] and item ball in Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, enumerate

Beamer item balls go missing while compiling in `XeLateX` since yesterday's `TeXlive` update, however, the same code works with `pdfLaTeX`. Any solution, please. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[ball]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A tested title}
text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item this is an item
\end{enumerate}
text3
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is due to the issue reported here https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/928
It has been fixed in the sources, so should be resolved soon.

Until then you can add the fix manually

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[ball]

\makeatletter

\def\pgfutil@insertatbegincurrentpagefrombox#1{%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\the\wd\pgfutil@abb}%
  \global\setbox\pgfutil@abb\hbox{%
    \unhbox\pgfutil@abb%
    \hskip\dimexpr2in-2\hoffset-\pgf@temp\relax% changed
    #1%
    \hskip\dimexpr-2in-2\hoffset\relax% new
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A tested title}
text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item this is an item
\end{enumerate}
text3
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```