# Bullets not showing with Beamer and XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex

I have the following presentation that I compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, svgnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
    \frametitle{Learning Outcomes}
    \begin{enum}
        \item Mathematical in nature
        \item Many abstract concepts $\rightarrow$ Requires abstract thinking $\rightarrow$ Formal logic
        \item Programming requires remembering syntax and semantics of programming statements
    \end{enum}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it the bullets are missing. All I see is this:

[image]

Removing `\usetheme{Madrid}` works fine and pdflatex works without any issues as well. Any solutions?

Comment: Instead of the `enum` environment, use either `enumerate` or `itemize`. If I try to compile your document, I get an error message complaining about `enum` being undefined.

Comment: @leandriis same issue with `itemize` and `enumerate`. `pdflatex` works but `xelatex` doesn't. No bullets.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565431/xelatex-update-20201004-and-item-ball-in-beamer/565433#565433

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try it out.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I’ve posted an answer with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ulrike Fischer pointed out above, this issue has already been solved at [XeLaTeX update [20201004] and item ball in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565431/xelatex-update-20201004-and-item-ball-in-beamer/565433#565433)