# The latest xelatex update make the beamer ball disappeared

Tags: beamer, xetex

I update the texlive update to date, and find the ball type outlines of beamer disappeared when using xelatex to compile, but lualatex work(the un-updated xelatex also work). But lualatex is so slow, I'd like to use xelatex than it.
Here are the compile results of the beamer conference talk example. The first is xelatex and the other is the original pdf from texlive.

[image: xelatex]

[image: original]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565431/xelatex-update-20201004-and-item-ball-in-beamer/