# \pgfuseshading is broken in XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, bugs

I am seeing some strange behavior when using `\pgfuseshading` in `xelatex`: compared to `pdflatex`, the gradient is shifted to the right by an unspecified amount.

Example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  paperwidth=8cm,
  paperheight=4.5cm,
  margin=0.5cm
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{shading}{3cm}{%
  color(0pt)=(red);
  color(\paperwidth)=(blue)}

\begin{document}
  \noindent A \dotfill A\\
  \pgfuseshading{shading}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: output of xelatex]

using `xelatex` but

[image: output of pdflatex]

using `pdflatex`.

I am running TeXLive 2020 with the latest updates (as of today). Interestingly, I do not see this behavior on another computer with an older version of TeXLive (2019). Is this a bug? Can I fix it locally in my document?

Comment: use the patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565433/2388 (insert the redefinition after loading tikz naturally).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That fixes it, thank you! If you write it as an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise, I can also answer it myself if you prefer.