# Beamer: Rounded shadows not displaying correctly in XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, shadows, rounded-corners

Yesterday I decided to install "vanilla" TeXLive after a couple of months with the Ubuntu repositories version. Everything works great, except that shadows at the corner of Beamer are not displaying when compiling with **XeLaTeX**, just as the image. I already tried with Okular, Evince and TeXMaker's viewer.

It used to work just fine with the Ubuntu version.

I have not been able to find something similar.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
\title{This is a test}
\usetheme{Madrid}%%         Tried other themes, they're also broken
\usecolortheme{default}%%   Tried other colors, they're also broken
%
\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\end{document}
```

**Images with the result:**

[image: Shadows clearly not working]

[image: Zoom on corners]

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, i'm compiling with XeLaTeX. pdfLaTeX works fine.

Comment: use the patch from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565433/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yep, that does it, thanks a lot

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes, adding that (as Ulrike Fischer also suggested), works. Thanks.

Comment: While this question already had an answer, I'm very thankful it was asked because the symptom I was experiencing was broken shadows around corners, *not* the original issue with enumerated items.